# One of the graphs is not plotting in MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, graph, plot, figure

I have three graphs to plot. They all plot fine alone, but when I want the graphs plotted in separate windows,  the second graph is not plotted.

This first graph plots fine:

```
function wave = carrier( t )
    %The carrier signal is a sine wave
    wave=sin(10*pi*t);
    %Plots the carrier wave
    figure(1);
    plot(wave);
    title('Figure 1: ASK Carrier signal')
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Amplitude')
end
```

This is the second graph which does not plot:

```
% Generates the data signal then plots it. The data signal is: 10110100
function [ D ] = data( t )
    %Genereates the data signal
    D=[ones(1,100) zeros(1,100) ones(1,100) ones(1,100) zeros(1,100) ones(1,100) zeros(1,100) zeros(1,100)];
    %Plots the data signal
    figure(2);
    plot(t,D);
    title('Figure 2: Data signal')
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Amplitude')
end
```

Finally, this is the third graph that plots:

```
function [ modulated ] = ASK( t )
%Using '.*'to multiply the arrays element by element
    modulated=data(t).*carrier(t);
    figure(3);
    %plots both the ASK and the data signal on the same graph
    plot(t,modulated,t,data(t), 'LineWidth',2);
    title('Figure 3: ASK modulated wave')
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Amplitude')
    legend('ASK (t)','data(t)')
%     for i=1:1:10;
%       %adding noise to simulate real life transmission of data
%         modulated(round(rand(1)*800))=rand(1);
%     end

end
```

How can I make all three graphs plot fine in separate windows?
This is what it looks like: http://prntscr.com/2i75xg
BTW, already tried subplot, same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `data` makes figure 2 the active figure. You call `data` in the plot command in the function `ASK` which makes figure 2 active. That's why nothing is displayed in figure 3.

You probably want something like this in `ASK`:

```
d = data(t);
figure(3)
plot(t, modulated, t, d, 'LineWidth'2);
```

Comment: so how would I plot data, as well as plotting the graph in figure 3?

Comment: See my edit. Alternately, make separate functions for calculations and for plots.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make the plots work for all 3 functions, but only if the input vector, t, has a length of exactly 800. This is because in the function data, you hardcode D to have a length of 800:

```
D=[ones(1,100) zeros(1,100) ones(1,100) ones(1,100) zeros(1,100) ones(1,100) zeros(1,100) zeros(1,100)];
```

If you pass anything else in, you will receive an error that "vector lengths must match."

Comment: Molly has it right, didn't catch the call to data after the "figure(3)" in the ASK function!